# Datasets not available in 3.6 R

Tags: r

When following youtube of vamsidhar ambatipudi on Mktg analytics tutorial videos I found a few data sets which could not be tested on R 3.6,it said such data not available in 3.6,his was on R 3.2.How can I work on such Datasets in R. For example Storesales dataset, National football league, Internet sales, used cars etc. Pls help.

Comment: If you're looking at this video, the first dataset is not a built-in one but came from elsewhere: https://youtu.be/veB2OIH7Gec?list=PLheFgWAePSu8O56C7Uhw9CrzUNRV_a83T&t=167

Comment: True. But if I have to work on R 3.6 is there any way out. If yes pls suggest for my practice